# Is there a way to adjust the axes limits of pairplot(), but not as individual plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Is there a way to adjust the axes limits of pairplot(), but not as individual plots? Maybe a setting to produce better axes limits?

I would like to have the plots with a bigger range for the axes.  My plots axes allows all the data to be visualized, but it is too 'zoomed in'.

My code is:

```py
import pandas as pd
mport matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_style('darkgrid')

g = sns.pairplot(iris, hue = 'species', diag_kind = 'hist', palette = 'Dark2', plot_kws={"s": 20})
```

The link for my plot and what I would like to plot to look like is here:
[pairplot](https://github.com/BB-Data/pairplot_iris_data/blob/main/Iris_pairplot.ipynb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the subplots, [`g.map(func, <parameters>)`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.PairGrid.map.html#seaborn.FacetGrid.map) can be used. A small problem is that `func` needs to accept `color` as parameter, and `plt.margins()` gives an error when `color` is used. Moreover, `map` uses `x` and `y` to indicate the row and column variables. You could write a dummy function that simply calls `plt.margin()`, for example `g.map(lambda *args, **kwargs: plt.margins(x=0.2, y=0.3))`.

An alternative is to loop through `g.axes.flat` and call `ax.margins()` on each of them. Note that many axes are shared in x and/or y direction. The diagonal is treated differently; for some reason `ax.margins` needs to be called a second time on the diagonal.

To have the histogram for the different colors stacked instead of overlapping, `diag_kws={"multiple": "stack"}` can be set.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_style('darkgrid')
iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
g = sns.pairplot(iris, hue='species', diag_kind='hist', palette='Dark2',
                 plot_kws={"s": 20}, diag_kws={"multiple": "stack"})
# g.map(plt.margins, x=0.2, y=0.2) # gives an error
for ax in g.axes.flat:
    ax.margins(x=0.2, y=0.2)
for ax in g.diag_axes:
    ax.margins(y=0.2)
plt.show()
```

[image: pairplot with changed margins]

PS: still another option, is to change the `rcParams` which will have effect on all the plots created later in the code:

```
import matplotlib as mpl

mpl.rcParams['axes.xmargin'] = 0.2
mpl.rcParams['axes.ymargin'] = 0.2
```

Comment: You can also get a flat list of every Axes object in the figure with `g.fig.axes`.

Comment: Thank you for the comments and solutions!  I appreciate it.  Will try them out and respond.

Comment: Can you perhaps help with this question I posted: "lmplot() regression lines are truncated"?  I did not receive replies on this.  Thank you